# Cannot access array props after mapStateToProps (after action/reducer)

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am making a React app with redux and am having trouble accessing the new state in my component after pushing to an array.

I have 2 reducers, todosReducer, baseReducer combined with a combineReducer.

This is todoReducer:

```
export default (state = Immutable.Map, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'newTodo':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos : state.todos.concat(createNewTodo(action.type))
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Basically I want it to add a new todo entry (returned by createNewTodo) to the todos property. In my jsx component I have the following:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        test: state.get("base").test,
        todos: state.get("todos").todos
    };
}
```

I cannot access anything from state.get("todos") in my render method. If I do:

```
console.log(state.get("todos").todos[0])
console.log(state.get("todos").todos.length)
```

I can get that the # of todos is 1 output to the console, but I cannot access any property of the todos object in my render method.

Comment: Can you show your render method?

Comment: Can you try `state.base.test` and `state.todos.todos` in your `mapStateToProps` function?

Comment: If I do state.todos.todos in mapStateToProps the page doesn't load and I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined"

Comment: Found the issue! In my render method I was accessing this.props.todos[property] instead of this.props.todos[index][property]. Arghhhh, thanks for the help guys!